Error compiling file
Sorry if this is something obvious, as I'm just getting into LaTeX. I installed TeX Live 2024 recently, and I'm using the VSC LaTeX Workshop extension. When I attempted to compile, it returned the following:
I'm running Windows 11, and I don't think it's relevant but I also didn't install the TeXworks frontend when I installed TeX Live. I also have Perl v5.38.2. Edit: It still seems to work (the pdf looks all correct).
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP437, CP437, CP1252)
I changed them all to CP1252
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 Mar. 2024. Version 4.84.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'k5.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'k5.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'k5.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'k5.pdf'
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required:
    Reason or flag: 'Initial setup'

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./k5.aux) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ot1qcr.fd) [1{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-rmm.enc}] [2 <./sampletrace.png>] (./k5.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )<c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qcrr.pfb>
Output written on k5.pdf (2 pages, 196442 bytes).
SyncTeX written on k5.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on k5.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'k5.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'k5.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'k5.log'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'k5.pdf'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  k5.aux

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./k5.aux) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ot1qcr.fd) [1{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-rmm.enc}] [2 <./sampletrace.png>] (./k5.aux) )<c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qcrr.pfb>
Output written on k5.pdf (2 pages, 196442 bytes).
SyncTeX written on k5.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on k5.log.
'k5.pdf' and 'c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5.pdf' are identical (not copied) at c:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 5562.
  That failed, with message 'No such file or directory'
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,437)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'k5.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'k5.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'k5.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'k5.pdf'
================='.', 'c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime' '', 'c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/'
Latexmk: Copying 'k5.pdf' to 'c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5.pdf'
C:\texlive\2024\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime/k5


That is not a tex error you got a perl error from latexmk while it was checking the file to see if anything had changed and it needed to run latex again.  can't see what is wrong although you seem to have specified --outdir to be the directory with the main document which is a bit strange, try without that.

I have the same experience with VSCode on Mac OS 14.4.1 after having just updated to TeX Live 2024.  While I agree with the principles of the above two comments, I also find that this bug is an annoyance as it seems to be preventing the PDF in VSCode from auto-refreshing to the new version.

The error message from latexmk that you see at the end of the run is caused by a bug in the new version of latexmk (4.84) combined with the specification of -outdir=c:/Users/Shingo/Desktop/latextime on the command line (which I think is done by LaTeX Workshop).  The use of an absolute path is one of the things that triggers the bug.
Latexmk is being reverted to 4.83 on CTAN, because of this bug, which was already reported by a maintainer of LaTeX Workshop.
Since the error occurs at the end of the run, i.e., after all compilations are complete, the generated pdf file is correct.
The bug is associated with the implementation of a new feature in latexmk 4.84, called a final-output directory, and accessed by the --out2dir=... option.  (See the latexmk documentation for the rationale for this new feature.)
A fix should be available soon.

I updated my latexmk yesterday with TeX Live Utility and that fixed the problem for me.  @Arden, if updating latexmk also fixes this problem for you, I recommending accepting this answer.

works with 4.85

nope i still have the same problem with 4.85 what else could it be?
